# Trouble converting Firebase Storage data to UIImage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download an image from Firebase Storage and show it in my iOS app. I have the following code:

```
func getSponsorImages() {
    guard let name = self.name, let city = self.city else { return }
    let refString = "cities/\(city)/sponsors/\(name)/photos"
    ref.child(refString).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot], snapshots.count != 0 {
            for snap in snapshots {
                let imageRef = storageRef.child("cities/\(city)/\(name)/\(snap.value!)")
                imageRef.getData(maxSize: 50*1024*1024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error getting image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        guard let photoData = data else { return }
                        guard let photo = UIImage(data: photoData) else { return }
                        self.photos.append(photo!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    })
}
```

The data is being returned, and no error is thrown, but when I try and create a UIImage from the Data, it crashes. Does anyone know why it's returning invalid data? I have also made sure that my Firebase rules are set properly.

Comment: Why do you have `UIImage(photo!)` and not just `UIImage(photo)` - no `!` ? `photo` can't be optional due to the `guard`. And what is your error? And which line exactly crashes?

Comment: What is the error that u get ?

Comment: I don't get an error, that's the issue. It's returning data, but the data can't be turned into a UIImage